# Bootstrap4 Default Values Within Form

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following form that I am trying to customize using bootstrap4. It looks like the formatting is working, but when I try and default the values in my edit form to the current values, they appear in a second text box below the form I just created. How would I adjust this code so the values are defaulted in my desired text box?

[image]

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.employee.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.employee.id_for_label }}"></label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Log the employee">
    {{ form.employee }}
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Who does this individual report to?</small>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your form code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `form.employee.value` into `input` tag as value attribute.

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.employee.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.employee.id_for_label }}"></label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Log the employee" value="{{ form.employee.value }}">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Who does this individual report to?</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the .value portion that I was missing